# Read Indirect state Vs. Read Direct state of a variable in java

Tags: java, static

In following code compilation fails for `static` variable `j` inside the static block, as mentioned in comment.

However, It is working fine inside the method `m1()`

```
class StaticBlock {
    static {
        m1();
        //compilation fails because variable are in read indirect state
        System.out.println(j);
    }

    static void m1() {
        System.out.println(j);
    }

    static int j = 10;
```

I know root cause of compilation failure - variable `j` is in Read Indirect State.

My question- Why is this behavior, we can also print `0` inside static block as we are doing in `m1()`.

What made API developers to have this discrepancy

Comment: I'd characterize it differently: [section 8.3.3 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3) says that the reference to `j` by a static initializer that precedes `j`'s declaration is a compile-time error.  Period. There's no need to introduce any kind of state terminology, and in fact it's confusing to do so, because the state in question is the state of the code, whereas we normally use the term to describe runtime properties of classes and objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this behavior, we can also print `0` inside static block as we
>   are doing in `m1()`.
>
> What made API developers to have this discrepancy

There are competing priorities revolving around simple specifications for the order of events during class initialization, consistency of constant (i.e. `final`) class fields, programmer expectations, and ease of implementation.

The values of constant fields provides a good starting point.  Java would like to avoid the default values of such fields being observable, and especially to avoid their default values being used in the initialization of other class variables.  Therefore, these are initialized first, before static initializer blocks or the initializers of other class variables.  They are initialized in the order they appear in the source code, which is a rule that is easy for both humans and compilers to understand.  But that affords the possibility that the initializer of one class variable sees the default value of another, yielding surprising, unwanted results.  Java therefore specifies that that case must be detected and rejected at compile time.

Static initializer blocks and the initializers of other class variables are executed afterward, in the order they appear in the source code.  The case for the constraint you're asking about is not as strong here, but it's reasonable to choose consistency by applying the same rule here as is applied to class constants. Combined, the effect is to have easy to understand and predict initialization order that is also mostly consistent with a model of class variables' initializers being evaluated and assigned before static initializer blocks are evaluated.

But then come static methods.  It is highly desirable for static methods to be available for use during initialization, but they are also usable after initialization is complete, when none of the initialization-order considerations are relevant.  It is therefore unfeasible to restrict static methods' access to variables based on order of appearance in source code.  Conceivably, the VM could instead be required to keep track of class variables' individual initialization state, either by control-flow analysis at compile time or by some form of runtime monitoring, but rather than require such complexities, Java opts for simplicity, allowing people who insist on making a mess (by observing default values of class variables) to do so.

I emphasize, finally, that so-called "Read Indirect Write Only state" is part of a third-party model of how this all works.  Java itself has no such concept -- such a thing is exactly what it rejects in favor of simplicity when it comes to requirements on static methods' use of class variables.